# Computing $\lim_{n\to\infty} [\frac{n-1}{n}]$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have a slight problem computing $\lim_{n\to\infty} [\frac{n-1}{n}]$. ( $[.]$ denotes the floor fonction). I know that the limit cannot "go inside" as the fonction is not continuous in the integers. I have attempted to use the inequality: $[x] \leq x < [x]+1$ but that was also unsuccessful.

Comment: Is this $\frac{n-1}{n}$ or $n-\frac{1}{n}$ in the floor?  In the former case, the value of the floor function is $0$ while in the later case, the value of the floor function is $n-1$.

Comment: [Question edited]

Answer (score 3):

For $n>1$, $[n-\frac{1}{n}]=n-1$. Thus the limit is $\infty$.

---

Now that you have changed the question, one should note that
$$
\biggr[\frac{n-1}{n}\biggr]=0
$$
for all $n>1$, and the limit is $0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it seems slightly unintuitive to me: we have [(n-1)/n] never reaching 1 when taking limits to infinity (whereas (n-1)/n tends to 1). I know that the two are not the same as the limits cannot commute, but is this answer just supposed to be accepted, or is there a more rigorous explanation?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Are you asking why the limit and the floor function do not commute?

Comment: Let $f(x)=[x]$ and denote $a_n=\frac{n-1}{n}$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=1$ but $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=0$ since $f(a_n)=0$ for every $n>1$. What is the confusion??

Comment: Ok, I get it now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left [ n - \frac{1}{n} \right ] > n - \frac{1}{n} - 1 \longrightarrow \infty$$

---

Now since you've changed the question : $$\left [ \frac{n-1}{n}\right ] = \left [1-\frac{1}{n}\right ] = 0$$

Thus the limit is 0.

Comment: Sadly the question has changed.  Perhaps a quick edit?

Comment: Done.­­­­­­­­­­